# C#, SQL and EF - Unique columns, call a database check or just try / catch the error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a situation where we have a growing tables of unique rows, currently at 11.6 million rows and will continue to grow significantly.

The main column is a unique index, and this is checked before additional data is uploaded into the table and an error report generated noting the duplicate rows.

I realise this is then making a database query to find if the record exists, and then an insert if it doesn't. I'm thinking of a couple of options to mitigate / reduce the database load, especially as the table grows and making lots of look ups becomes inefficient.

**Option 1**, look to batch up the exists check to find a list of records that do exist and then check against that before the insert.

**Option 2**, just try the insert, capture the exception and use that to build the error report.

Option 2 may perform better? But does seem to smell... Are there any efficient strategies for checking duplicates before an insert?

Comment: A stored procedure that checks itself the duplication before inserting could be an approach to test.

Comment: @Steve would a SP still do a `SELECT` and then an `INSERT`? Just self contained in the database, so the code would make a single call.

Comment: Search for IF EXISTS or MERGE or look into the Mr Linoff answer. This could be done in the SP and then let this return 0 or 1 to communicate success or failure

Comment: Use MERGE for such situation and forgot about LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually option 1 that smells.  What you are forgetting is *time*.  There is time between any check you make and running the `insert` query.  During that time, the underlying tables can change -- invalidating your check.

SQL offers a great solution for this, `on conflict`.  But SQL Server does not support that.  Alas.

The problem is that SQL Server rejects the *entire* `insert` if even one row has an issue.  There is no problem for singleton inserts.

But if you are inserting multiple rows, then often this is approached by using something like:

```
insert into t ( . . . )
     select . . .
     from staging s
     where not exists (select 1 from t where t.uniquecol = s.uniquecol);
```

You can also phrase this using `merge`.

Comment: |That a good point on option 1, I'm thinking in isolation rather than generically (d'oh!) - in this scenario the update file comes in every 3 hours, so no timing issues but obviously it could be a big problem for any other situation. The temp table is a good idea

Comment: @RemarkLima . . . If the batch process is the only process that changes the table and it is run at wide intervals, then there is *generally* little problem.  Issues do arise when something happens and you are debugging one batch while the next batch gets started.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking that just bunging a `try` `catch` around some code just seems a bit iffy, but the performance hit on the database is probably worse... But this doesn't feel like best practise, hence a temp table to do the `INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS` is the cleanest. The error report can be generated from the opposite query before clearing the table